# Next.js SSR Caching using custom server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How do I implement Caching at SSR for Next.js
They have mentioned SSR Caching
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server
which is not working
Apparently Next.js have made **app.renderToHTML()** as obsolete and cant be used with **getServerSideProps** function and using **app.render()** in the caching function which always gives undefined and breaks with the following error

```
(node:20872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: argument entity is required
at etag (C:\xampp\htdocs\next-app\node_modules\etag\index.js:72:11)
at C:\xampp\htdocs\next-app\node_modules\cacheable-response\index.js:93:32
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
(node:20872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20872) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

because of which the above example breaking.

Here is the github link where I have raised an issue
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25579

Can any one help me in this?

Comment: Have you had a look at their official [SSR caching example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/ssr-caching)?

Comment: Yes. That is the one which I am talking about.
Which is not working

Comment: They do not use `renderToHTML` in that example, as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: But prviously it was working well with renderToHTML.
now its render function which give undefined in caching function
here is the github url where i have raised the issue

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [solution](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25621#issuecomment-855151444) suggested by @awareness481 on github seems to fix the issue for me and I can confirm that the cache is also working. I tested it by putting a trace in `get` method of `cachableResponse` just before `app.render` which only gets called if there is no cached response.

Also testing the blog pages via Postman, I am getting header `X-Cache-Status` as `HIT` after first call and response time has reduced from `>300` to `<20`